# ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream() doesn't load with relative path in Java 7 U 7

Tags: javafx-2, java-7

Problem statement: ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream() doesn't load / find the resource if path to is relative. If the path is absolute, it works fine.

I recently upgraded from Java 6 with JavaFx 2.1 to Java SE 7 u 7 with JavaFX 2.2. It worked fine in the earlier version of JAvaFX 2.0 / Java FX 2.1. IDE used is NetBean IDE 7.2.

I am facing an issue which I find very strange. I created a JAVA FX project using IDE and tried to load the properties file. It works fine when absolute path is specified. But when I change to relative path it fails with exception.

**ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("../resources/newproperties.properties");** // Doesn't work.

**ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/newproperties.properties");** // Works with absolute path.

Then I created another Simple Java project in Netbeans 7.2 IDE with JAva 7u7 and tried to load the property file using ClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("../newproperties.properties");. It works fine both with relative and absolute path. Basically, if it is JAVAFX 2.2 project, it doesn't load. Where if its a simple java project, the same code works which I find it very strange.

Note: the above code was working fine with Java 6 with Javafx 2.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to perform "Clean and Build"?

Comment: Yes I did clean and build multiple times. Also, created new sample JavaFx projects on Netbean IDE 7.2 to test this. If the project is just a java project it worked, but didn't work if JavaFX project.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is packaged as a jar (as JavaFX apps normally are), then the jar protocol used in the underlying implementation of the get resource operation won't resolve the parent `..` specifier in the relative path.

If your app is not packaged and is simply a collection of class and other files in the file system, then the `..` specifiers will resolve because the resource lookup will use a file protocol as opposed to a jar protocol.

Sample demonstrating the above points:

```
package classpathtest;

public class ClassPathTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ClassPathTest.class.getResourceAsStream("../roundbutton.css"));
  }
}
```

Use of sample.

```
C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes>echo any text > roundbutton.css

C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes>echo Main-Class: classpathtest.ClassPathTest > manifest.txt

C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes>jar cvfm ClassPathTest.jar manifest.txt roundbutton.css classpathtest
added manifest
adding: roundbutton.css(in = 521) (out= 257)(deflated 50%)
adding: classpathtest/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: classpathtest/ClassPathTest.class(in = 680) (out= 399)(deflated 41%)

C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes>java -jar ClassPathTest.jar
null

C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes>java classpathtest.ClassPathTest
java.io.BufferedInputStream@927e4be

C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes>java -version
java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b54)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b21, mixed mode)

C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes>dir /s
 Directory of C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes

09/12/2012  02:31 PM    <DIR>          classpathtest
09/12/2012  02:37 PM             1,414 ClassPathTest.jar
09/12/2012  02:36 PM                42 manifest.txt
09/12/2012  02:31 PM               521 roundbutton.css

 Directory of C:\dev\javafx\ClassPathTest\build\classes\classpathtest

09/12/2012  02:31 PM               680 ClassPathTest.class
```

If `java -jar ClassPathTest.jar` does not return null for you on earlier jdk versions, but does return null for you on jdk7u7+, then you have found a jdk bug.  I haven't tested other jdk versions than the one I have installed, but I think the likelihood of there being a jdk bug related to this is low.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked in my project in netbeans 7.2, JavaFx Project --> Properties --> Build --> Packaging, it is packaged as .jar. Even the simple Java project is packaged as jar and it is able to load the resource. Where as the same source not running in JavaFx project. Also, my earlier version of JAvafx 2.0 & JavaFX 2.1 were packaged as jars and they were able to load the resource. Only in the latest version JavaFX 7u7 its not loading.

Comment: Updated answer to include test sample.

Comment: When we run the jar from command prompt it won't recognize the resource files. It happens in all versions and no doubt about it. The problem I am observing is when I ran the application within the IDE then it ran with relative URL(In the JAVAFX 2.0 version), but when I updgraded to Javfx2.2 with Java 7u7, then it isn't running with in the IDE with relative URL. It wants with reference to the root starting with a "/". So I'do like to know what made the same code  fail in latest version.

Comment: NetBeans (prior to 7.2) used to allow you to run JavaFX applications by executing against classes on the filesystem.  I believe NetBeans 7.2 changed so that when you run a JavaFX app it must run from a jar (try right-clicking on a java file to try to run a file in a JavaFX project and you will see a new message in NetBeans 7.2 which prevents you from doing so).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I observed that Netbeans 7.2 doesn't allow single file execution(Only for JavaFX projects), inside from the application. For simple java project it does allow single file execution. That's why it worked with relative path and made me think some issue with new version. Thanks again for all the help.